# Creating a dictionary of dictionaries from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, row

I am trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries in Python from a CSV file, the file looks something like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | flower | 12 |
| A | sun | 13 |
| B | cloud | 14 |
| B | water | 34 |
| C | rock | 12 |

And I am trying to get a dictionary of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
    dict = {
        'A': {'flower': 12, 'sun': 13},
        'B': {'cloud': 14, 'water': 34},
        'C': {'rock': 12}
                   }
```

The code I tried so far is as follows:

```
import csv 
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvFile:  
    rows=csv.reader(csvFile) 
    d=dict()     
    for row in rows: 
        head,tail=row[0], row[1:] 
        d[head]=dict(zip(tail[0:], tail[1:])) 
    print(d)
```

but it's not working well as I am getting this result:

```
dict = {
        'A': {'sun': 13},
        'B': {'water': 34},
        'C': {'rock': 12}
                   }
```

Comment: I wish you hadn't formatted the data as a table. That's not useful for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your `d[head]` every iteration, not replace it:

```
import csv 
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvFile:  
    rows=csv.reader(csvFile) 
    d=dict()     
    for row in rows:
        head,name,value=row[0], row[1], row[2]
        if head not in d:
            d[head]= {} # {} is like dict() but faster
        d[head][name] = value
    print(d)
```

Or with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to be more concise:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvFile:  
    rows=csv.reader(csvFile) 
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for row in rows:
        head,name,value=row[0], row[1], row[2]
        d[head][name] = value
    print(d) # or print(dict(d))
```

Comment: To be even more concise: `for head,name,d[head][name] in rows: pass`

Comment: Thank you! what does the d[head][name] = value is actually doing, please?

Comment: `d[key]` access the value under dictionary. In our case, value is another dictionary. Then we set value of that subdictionary. You could write it `subdict = d[head]` then `subdict[name] = value`

Comment: You can also use [**`dict.setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).